# Hacker rank Clases addition for Rest api task

Tags: spring-boot

I have been provided with a task of creating a Rest Api for a provided situation and I tried creating it in my IDE but when I am trying to copy it in Hackerrank editor it's giving a compilation error for the Annotations that I have added for creating the rest api like `@SpringBootApplication` and `@RestController`.

I did it on IDE locally and copied all my classes to the single editor that is provided for running your code but its giving compilation errors on various Annotations used.

Can someone let me know what is the way of creating different classes in the editor if you have multiple classes in your solution with some extra annotations.

Comment: have u forgot to import packages in top of class? sometimes we forgot to import inadvertently

Comment: Ohh.Ya I didn't copied the imports. let me try if that helps.

Comment: i tried addig the imports but its still saying "package org.springframework.boot does not exist" .

Answer (score 0):

You need add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

then it will work.
Refer to [this](https://support.hackerrank.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005563048-Taking-a-Role-based-Assessment-) hacker rank link to get and idea about where should libraries be input.